# How to transform image to its hex color values

Tags: image-processing, text, colors

Let's suppose these are pixels of an image.
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKRhL.png

How do I transform them into a txt file containing all hex color values ?
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jXnT.jpg

Comment: What did you try, where did it fail and how does your [mre] look like? What coding language do you use? What frameworks?

Comment: Please read [ask] to provide better questions and not risk getting downvoted / closevoted. Please do not post images of text - add it as text by [edit]ing your question. If you got code, post a [mre] of what you got and explain why it does not fullfill your needs

Answer (score 3):

With **ImageMagick** in Terminal maybe:

```
magick image.png txt:
```

**Output**

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 3,2,65535,srgb
0,0: (254,19,17)  #FE1311  srgb(254,19,17)
1,0: (84,11,255)  #540BFF  srgb(84,11,255)
2,0: (161,12,255)  #A10CFF  srgb(161,12,255)
0,1: (117,251,21)  #75FB15  srgb(117,251,21)
1,1: (250,227,22)  #FAE316  srgb(250,227,22)
2,1: (27,247,255)  #1BF7FF  srgb(27,247,255)
```

---

Or maybe a little closer:

```
magick image.png rgb:- | xxd -g3 -c3

00000000: fe1311  ...
00000003: 540bff  T..
00000006: a10cff  ...
00000009: 75fb15  u..
0000000c: fae316  ...
0000000f: 1bf7ff  ...
```

---

Or, even closer:

```
magick image.png rgb:- | xxd -g3 -c3 | awk '{print $2}'

fe1311
540bff
a10cff
75fb15
fae316
1bf7ff
```

Or, if using v6 ImageMagick, replace `magick` with `convert`.

Answer (score 1):

In ImageMagick starting with version 6.9.8.9, you can do:

```
convert image.png -crop 1x1 +repage -depth 8 -format "%[hex:s]\n" info:
```

Where "s" is the current image in the command line chain.

So for example if I make a 1x10 gradient image:

```
magick -size 1x10 gradient: -crop 1x1 +repage -depth 8 -format "%[hex:s]\n" info:

FFFFFF
E3E3E3
C6C6C6
AAAAAA
8E8E8E
717171
555555
393939
1C1C1C
000000
```